# Beamer, framebreaks with different subtitles

Tags: beamer, titles

A frame in Beamer presentation can be broken in number frames with the same frame title. Those titles can be subsequently enumerated. Is there way, that in such cases each slide in common frame with common title have individual subtitles for belonging slides? As you can see from minimal example, now is considered last subtitle as common subtitle for slides ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphics,tikz}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Common title, appearing on all slides in one frame}
\framesubtitle{The first frame subtitle}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 1
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 2
\framebreak
\framesubtitle{The second frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots
\end{itemize}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 3
\framebreak
\framesubtitle{The third frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not individual slides and no complications? Also you can use `\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle} ..... \end{frame}` to ease the typing load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `allowframebreaks`; the documentation of `beamer` has the following recommendation:

> Using the `allowframebreaks` option invites the creation of horrible,
>   endless presentations that resemble more a "paper projected on the
>   wall" than a presentation. Nevertheless, the option does have its
>   uses. Most noticeably, it can be convenient for automatically
>   splitting bibliographies or long equations.

You can use overlay specifications instead; here's an example using `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphics,tikz}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Common title, appearing on all slides in one frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 1
\only<1>{
\framesubtitle{The first frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 1
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 2
\only<2>{
\framesubtitle{The second frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 2
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 3
\only<3>{
\framesubtitle{The third frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 3
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If verbatim material created with the `listings` package must be in the argument of `\only` (or any other command), then some precautions must be taken; the additional work is described in Section **5.1 Listings inside arguments** of the listings documentation (notice that this is an experimental feature):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings} 


 %---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Figures and Graphics}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\only<1>{
\framesubtitle{Including Graphics}
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
\\usepackage\{graphicx\}^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 2
\only<2>{
\framesubtitle{The second frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 2
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
%%------------------------------------------------------------ 3
\only<3>{
\framesubtitle{The third frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 3
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently only doesn't work with listings. Is that correct? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @MCB yes, it does. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have a question, if in the `\only<3>` I have a lot things that related to  "The third frame subtitle" so that the `\only<3>` cannot holds ,then what can I do ? breaks?

Comment: @Alex please feel free to ask a follow-up question, providing all necessay information there (you can also add a link to this question if it's relevent).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I just think this cannot support a question