# Frame break with different subtitles

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to have a frame with continuation title and have a different subtitle per each frame break? Following the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle 1}

test 1

\framebreak
\framesubtitle{Subtitle 2}

test 2

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that beamer takes 'Subtitle 2' for all slides.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems impossible.

Even the frame is presented in several pages due to the `\framebreak`, but  it is still only one frame in concept. And the subtitle of this particular frame has to be the same, though they display on several pages.

The first usage of the `\framesubtitle{Subtitle 1}` is replaced by the second `\framesubtitle{Subtitle 2}`, because they are setting the same property with two different parameters. That's why the "subtitle 2" is shown in all the pages.

Maybe you could try other ways adding information.

Here is another way to display different subtitle in separate pages of one frame:
[Beamer, framebreaks with different subtitles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/beamer-framebreaks-with-different-subtitles)