# how to break in \only

Tags: beamer

Since the `allowframebreaks` in the beamer has some side effects as put by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/beamer-framebreaks-with-different-subtitles), so in his answer to "[Beamer, framebreaks with different subtitles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/beamer-framebreaks-with-different-subtitles)", he recommend that `\only` should be a substitute. The following is the example he gives

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphics,tikz}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Common title, appearing on all slides in one frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 1
\only<1>{
\framesubtitle{The first frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 1
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots

\end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------------------ 2
\only<2>{
\framesubtitle{The second frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
\item some text on slide 2
\item some text
\item some text
\item   \dots 
\end{itemize}}  
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

My question is : if I have a little more things related to the title "The second frame subtitle" in the `\only<2>`, so that they cannot be put in one frame, then what I can do? Are there some similar command like `allowframebreaks` that can be used locally ?

Comment: What about: \only<3>{\framesubtitle{The second frame subtitle (cont.)} a little more things } for instance.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, and this is the natural idea, but I want to search for other method.

Answer (score 3):

(This is too long for a comment, but in some extent I think that it is also an answer).

I agree a lot with the quote from Beamer's documentation in the linked answer of Gonzalo's, but this is only a matter of style. For example, a long itemize list in four slides is really boring,  but the same awful result will be obtained with `\only` or another alternative method showing the screen I, II, III and IV with parts of the same list explained in subtitles, or several lists but about the same topic.

The implicit solution in this reference (the best IMHO), is to reduce/split your list to have no more than five or six items per topic (consider adding the frame a distinctive title) and redesign your presentation to have no more than a slide per topic.

On the other hand, there is nothing wrong using `allowframebreaks` from the technical point of view. If your list cannot be reduced/split, why not use it?  Here you cannot use different subtitles, but they would have little sense when showing only one list (therefore on the same topic) with already numbered titles.